# Ending Async Webforms execution

Tags: c#, webforms, async-await, .net-4.5

I inherited a large amount of WebForms pages that also act as their own JSON API. According to the parameters sent to them, these pages either:

- Return a fully-fledged HTML page.
- Return a JSON response and terminate the page using the dreaded
  `Response.End()`.

Now, I have to call some async code in these legacy JSON API, which I do using `RegisterAsyncTask` .

After the modification, we noticed the aspx page execution now continues even after the Response.End(). This causes a lot of crash reports as the page 'Model' is not -and should be- loaded when returning JSON.

I believe this is due to Response.End() calling `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort` to stop the process, while async are not always running on the UI thread.

Is there another way in ASP.NET than Response.End to prevent the .aspx from executing when the response is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any code, so I don't know where you're registering the tasks, but you can:

- Call Response.End() at [PreRenderComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.prerendercomplete).
- Call [ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks](Https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.executeregisteredasynctasks) after registering the tasks.

Comment: Thank you @Paulo, the ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks documentation really helps understand when async tasks are executed. We register our tasks in Page_Load. If we run ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks there, will it use the main thread to execute the async tasks?

Comment: I would choose using the date on `PreRenderComplete`.

Comment: After investigation I found that the ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks method is broken / obsolete, it only works with the 'legacy' AsyncTaskManager mode: [Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/LegacyPageAsyncTaskManager.cs)